# How to upload html file in the google and let it view by everyone?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have built a program using HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and PHP. I want to know how to put HTML file in the google so, people can use it or everyone can view it. I heard I need to do something with SEO then they will let mine program view by everyone.

Comment: Just index it with the [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about)

Answer (score 2):

you must buy `host` and `domain` and then upload your site in host you buy (you can search for free host and domain for first time) and then index it with the `google search console`